# Identify second line of text in a cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of cells that have two lines of text in each cell after pulling the data into Excel.
What I am looking to do is use a macro with the `Trim` function to remove everything in the cell after the second line.
I'm puzzled with this data, it's as if you were to enter data in a cell and Enter down to the next cell, but it's one cell and is not merged.

ex.

`Someone's Name [123]
Procedure room, procedure done`

Is there a way to identify this line break?

thanks so much for any assistance, my heads spinning and I'm punching out for the day.
cheers

Comment: Alt + Enter, creates a line break in cell. `TRIM` won't help as its not space. Use substitute. Like : `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")`

Comment: If you really do mean "remove everything in the cell after the **second** line", some tweaks will need to be made to the answers provided.  (But hopefully that is just a typo and you meant "first line".)

Comment: ah yes, I meant everything on the second line, so after first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look for the *ASCII-10*.  Select the cells you wish to process and run:

```
Sub KleanUp()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Split(r.Value, Chr(10))(0)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Only the first line will be retained in each cell.

**EDIT#1:**

As Ralph points out, *ASCII-13* should also be considered, therefore:

```
Sub KleanUp2()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Split(Replace(r.Value, Chr(13), Chr(10)), Chr(10))(0)
    Next r
End Sub
```

This converts to a single-style line-break.

**EDIT#2:**

It is possible to improve the performance of the sub by:

- reading the data into a VBA array  as a single large block
- looping through the array *(in VBA)*
- transferring the data back to the worksheet in a single block

Comment: There are several different possibilities for line breaks. `Chr(10)` is just one of them. You might want to include `vbCrLf` and `vbNewLine` just to render your solution more complete.

Comment: @Ralph  I will fix this.

Comment: The first one seems to work perfectly for what I intended. The edit is giving me a the error `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`
Now, to spend some time on google so I can understand what you've provided me with. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using a less strenuous method? I have 140k rows in my column that it is having to loop through, I had to close out after about 15 minutes of Excel not responding. I did turn off screen updating but doesn't seem to help much and that is about as far as my inexperience with VBA can take me.

Thanks much for any response.

Comment: @Awill  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: This is possible to do without knowing what the values of the cell should be? There are thousands of items that will change on a monthly basis. Sorry for my lack of understanding, I am trying to research how to execute the options you gave in edit # 2.

Comment: @Awill  **Which column holds the data you are trying to process ??**

Comment: Column 7 of my table. What I attempted was;
`Sub KleanUp()
    Dim r As Range
ActiveSheet.Range ("Table2").Columns (7).Select    
For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Split(r.Value, Chr(10))(0)
    Next r
End Sub`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130723/discussion-between-awill-and-garys-student).